# Flutter Row and Column Problems

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I am facing problems with Rows in flutter, I want to put my asset at the botton of the container, How can I do that using Row? I tried mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end, and cross.end but is not working...

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double wi = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
              width: wi,
              height: 200,
            ),
            Container(
              width: wi,
              height: 200,
              color: Colors.red,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                children: <Widget>[
                  SvgPicture.asset('assets/escapa.svg', semanticsLabel: 'Flask', color: Colors.black, width: 100,height: 100,)
                ]
              ),
              )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

[image: svg1]

[image: svg2]

you can download the asset/image.svg here 
http://filesharing24.com/d/DVh

Comment: Do you want one of the containers to fill the screen or is your problem the fact that image is not actually in the corner, and looks like it has a padding?

Comment: Yes it is I just added your code with Icon, it is aligned. Let me see, what SvgPicture do

Comment: @XavierVZ I just tried with a svg and it also aligning. Your svg is wrong I think. Try this svg cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0496/1029/files/Freesample.svg?5153 iif not work let me know.

Comment: ok  the svg was the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Container has property alignment use that,
you can either use it like this

```
alignment: Alignment(0.0, 0.0), // this means center, range is from -1 to +1
```

you would need to set it as Alignment(-1.0, 1.0)
or use it like this

```
alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
```

u don't need to play with row or column axis, container property should be enough.
play around with either one of the methods to get exact position

Comment: the problem was with my svg file, but it good to know that I can use alignment propertie inside Contaienrs